# v-on Click not working for bootstrap modal button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Bootstrap modal is linked with a button. I want to get some data on click. But the bootstrap default event is not letting the `v-on:click` event to trigger. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<a data-id="{{ $order->id }}" data-toggle="modal" class="changeartwork" data-target="#uploadModal" @click="getData()">Upload</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `v-on:click.prevent.stop="getData()"` instead. This will stop the on click bubbling up to Bootstrap and overriding it.

See here for more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Note: It's possible that `.prevent` would be enough but without a test case, I'm not sure so just give it a go and see which works.

Comment: actually I checked the page source and there is no v-on click directive, while other directives for other elements are there. What can be the problem

Comment: Page source? v-on:click won't show. It's removed as part of page processing by vue. `v-on:click` is just longhand for `@click`.

Comment: it don't event show @click in page source or any vue directive that i use for the modal button. The button is in the laravel else statement is that a problem

Comment: My answer answers your question. If you need more you need to provide more context and information. Currenly, it's not clear what you want if this answer doesn't help you.